# How to Force a Reload from the Server?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have a page that gets a default list of data from the server, and this page also has a search box that, when run, updates a query parameter and returns a new list of data to the same page. This works fine.

However, when I clear the search (either through an action or by hitting "back" in the browser), I want to get the default data fresh from the server, replacing whatever the search results were.

I think I have this most of the way there, because clearing out the query parameter does cause `findAll()` to ask the server for data again, and that also gives back the right data, but the store keeps all the previously retrieved records from the search, so now the user sees both the default set ***plus*** the records they got back from the search.

**So, how do I force Ember Data to use what comes back from the API and overwrite whatever it had in the store?**

Here's my route code. Despite having `reload: true` and `refreshModel: true`, it appears that neither are actually happening:

```
model: function(params) {
  if (params.q) {
    return this.store.find('project', params);
  } else {
    return this.store.findAll('project', {reload: true});
  }
},
queryParams: {
  q: {
    refreshModel: true
  }
},
```

Thanks in advance!

**Update:**
I noticed that the production environment doesn't have this problem. Whereas in Dev, or when running `ember serve --environment=development` the data isn't cleared out, and if I use `this.store.unloadAll('project')` before the `findAll()`, it seems to clear it out, but then gives me a "calling set on a destroyed object" error. But if I do `ember serve --environment=production` I don't get any errors. I don't know why this would be the case, but it's not the first time I've had massive headaches in Dev, only to find that running production is fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`store.unloadAll('project')`](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Store.html#method_unloadAll) method to purge all records from store before firing `findAll`.

Comment: Thanks, you would think so, but I have tried that, and if I put that one line in, then when navigating back to this route, it gives me an error: `Error while processing route: projects Assertion Failed: calling set on destroyed object`

Comment: Is there a way I can explicitly set the model from within the model hook? I don't know why that would be different than just returning the promise from findAll(), but I'm getting desperate here.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to have something to do with it:

[unloadingRecord w/ relationships fail in flushCanonical](https://github.com/emberjs/data/issues/3084)

and this (linked to in the above issue):

[[BUGFIX release] Guard against isDestroyed in ManyArray.flushCanonical #3559](https://github.com/emberjs/data/pull/3559)

Comment: Okay, so after days of frustration on this, it appears to have something to do with the way `ember build --environment=development` works as opposed to `environment=production` because the former causes errors, and the latter, with the same code base, does not.